# Slowly migrating an EDMX application to use a DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, edmx

I have a legacy EF 4 library with a database-first generated ObjectContext with EntityObjects. I'd like to slowly migrate to using DbContext and am in need of some guidence.

One of the overloads for DbContext takes an existing ObjectContext. I thought this would allow me to wrap my existing ObjectContext in a DbContext and expose my existing EntityObjects through IDbSet properties. Unfortunately, when creating the DbContext, the IDbSet properties are not created and instead an exception is thrown with a message of: "Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject."

Is there no way to use a DbContext with IDbSet exposing an existing ObjectContext and EntityObjects? It seems strange that I can create a DbContext with an ObjectContext, but not expose the entities themselves.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(MyObjectContext objectContext, bool dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
        : base(objectContext, dbContextOwnsObjectContext)
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

The exception is caused by the DbContext trying to create the IDbSet. Person is an EntityObject from my existing EDMX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, you cannot use the existing entity objects that the edmx created.

Have you considered using the [Reverse Engineer Code First power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)?

I've used them in several projects, and its simple as pointing it at your database, it generates the model in the same project, and then removing the edmx file.